# Is it possible to return an array from a MySQL Table?

Tags: mysql, arrays

I have 2 basic tables -- a main table containing master ID records and a related table containing a variable number of value references as shown below.

TABLE A: Main (one)

```
+----+-------------+
| ID | description |
+----+-------------+
| 1  | Arnold      |
+----+-------------+
| 3  | Baker       |
+----+-------------+
| 7  | Charlie     |
+----+-------------+
```

TABLE B: Related (Many)

```
+----+-------+
| ID | value |
+----+-------+
| 1  | 1     |
+----+-------+
| 1  | 2     |
+----+-------+
| 3  | 3     |
+----+-------+
| 3  | 2     |
+----+-------+
| 3  | 1     |
+----+-------+
| 7  | 2     |
+----+-------+
```

After joining Table A with Table B, is it possible to return the columns in such a way that the `value` column from Table B returns as an array?

I am looking to return something like the result set below (based on example above) where the 2nd column can be handled as an array value rather than a string value:

```
{
 [0] => 1
 [1] => array(1,2)
}
{
 [0] => 3
 [1] => array(3,2,1)
}
{
 [0] => 7
 [1] => array(2)
}
```

Here is my Query Statement to get the columns as string values:

```
SELECT tablea.*, tableb.value
FROM tablea
LEFT JOIN tableb ON tableb.ID = tablea.ID
```

Comment: From pure MySQL, no. If you're using a programming language (ie. PHP) then yes.

Comment: You'd have to "pack" the array into, say, a string (for storage), and unpack it after MySQL returns it. Something like "2 2 1" (use implode and explode in PHP).

Comment: So you mean the I will need to return the table b value as a string delimited by commas (for example) and then use PHP to do the conversion? That was what I was thinking would need to happen, but I wanted to ask if anyone had done it right through the query statement in mysql. Thanks for clarifying and answering @FreshPrinceOfSO

Comment: That's what I thought @PhilPerry -- thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically this is done by building up the multi-dimensional array when reading the result set with your application logic.  Here is some pseudo-code:

```
array = [];
while (row = {some DB row retrieval method}) {
    array[row['id']][] = row['value'];
}
```

If PHP is your language:

```
$array = array();
while ($row = {some DB row retrieval method}) {
    $array[$row['id']][] = $row['value'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks MikeBrant. Now I just need to get the right join query to collect the many rows in Table B and convert them into a single column for my result set.

Comment: @H.Ferrence You should break your question apart and update it.

Comment: @H.Ferrence That is simply `SELECT a.id, b.value FROM a INNER JOIN b on a.id = b.id`.

Comment: Thanks @MikeBrant -- I'l give that a try.

Comment: I am not entirely sure what you mean @FreshPrinceOfSO

Comment: Well, that returns each row from Table B each by itself. I need to figure out the MySQL query statement to get the Table B rows to condense into a single row and have their values separated by commas -- @MikeBrant. I think it is looking like I need to use `GROUP_CONCAT` for this

Comment: @H.Ferrence You can use GROUP_CONCAT, but that you will have to have an extra step in your application to explode that string concatenation into an array for each record.  I do not see where you gain anything by doing this.

Comment: I needed to use `GROUP_CONCAT` to get the "many" rows to compress into a string like `3,1,2` per my example. Using your suggestions, your code sample, and `GROUP_CONCAT` is exactly the result I am looking for @MikeBrant.

Comment: @H.Ferrence Your example didn't ask for a string of `3,1,2`, etc. but rather an array.  So if using GROUP_CONCAT, you would still need to explode the string to get an array.

Comment: Right. But the answer was that you cannot produce an array() out of a MySQL query. So you have to do something first to get the many rows into a string value that you can use to produce the array. So bottom-line is all the various feedback to my question from SO members, including yourself, led me to a working solution. Thanks, I greatly appreciate your help @MikeBrant.